# Download multiple files with multiple threads

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to download few files using 3 threads. my requirement is i want to achieve file download on 3 threads so that all files download 3 times in 3 different folders so that the files dont overwrite. I am using __counter to append 1,2,3 to the folders. Problem is if i give Thread count as 1 or 2 or 3 , it is behaving same in all the scenarios i.e. it always create two folders Folder1 and Folder2 and in all in folder1 it download all the files and in folder2 only last file gets downloaded with size as 0 KB.

Number of threads = 1

Attaching what i have tried so far-

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Please try without counter function and with prefix, and two threads. I am guessing it based on the below information.

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file

> Please note that Filename Prefix must not contain Thread related data,
>   so don't use any Variable (${varName}) or functions like
>   ${__threadNum} in this field

Or try to keep some delay/pacing between two threads.

Hope this helps.

Update:-
Just give the folder path and file name without extension. It will save the with extension. I tried with image and it is save as Myfile1.jpeg
[image]

Comment: How to get correct file extension in save response to a file, in save reponse to file if i harcode as MyFile.pdf then it comes as pdf i dont want to hardcode the extension i want to get file extension based on file what i am trying to download.

Comment: It is weird , i also tried with image and it worked but when tried with pdf/excel/docx it does not. can you try the same at your end ?

Comment: I am able to see the same response. Pdf get saved. But, there is a difference in mine request. My request is directly hitting the pdf file url where as yours is an upload request(by name) and having a file attached to download.

Comment: Where it is upload request ?

Comment: Reportfileupload.ashx in the path field of first screen shot.